# Magento 2: Any Difference between TYPE_NUMERIC and TYPE_DECIMAL?

Tags: magento2, migration, setup-upgrade, ddl

In Magento 2's migration/data-definition-language, there are two column type constants

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php
const TYPE_NUMERIC = 'numeric';
const TYPE_DECIMAL = 'decimal';
```

Is there **any** difference in table columns created with these constants?  It doesn't look like the `TYPE_NUMERIC` constant is used anywhere, so its unclear if its just legacy cruft, or somehow subtly different from `TYPE_DECIMAL`

Answer (score 3):

According to `framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`, they're <s>the</s> synonyms, meaning they're the same column type:

```
protected $_ddlColumnTypes      = [
    Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN       => 'bool',
    Table::TYPE_SMALLINT      => 'smallint',
    Table::TYPE_INTEGER       => 'int',
    Table::TYPE_BIGINT        => 'bigint',
    Table::TYPE_FLOAT         => 'float',
    Table::TYPE_DECIMAL       => 'decimal',
    Table::TYPE_NUMERIC       => 'decimal',
    Table::TYPE_DATE          => 'date',
    Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP     => 'timestamp',
    Table::TYPE_DATETIME      => 'datetime',
    Table::TYPE_TEXT          => 'text',
    Table::TYPE_BLOB          => 'blob',
    Table::TYPE_VARBINARY     => 'blob',
];
```

This is confirmed by the `_getColumnDefinition` method:

```
        case Table::TYPE_DECIMAL:
        case Table::TYPE_NUMERIC:
            $precision  = 10;
            $scale      = 0;
            $match      = [];
            if (!empty($options['LENGTH']) && preg_match('#^\(?(\d+),(\d+)\)?$#', $options['LENGTH'], $match)) {
                $precision  = $match[1];
                $scale      = $match[2];
            } else {
                if (isset($options['SCALE']) && is_numeric($options['SCALE'])) {
                    $scale = $options['SCALE'];
                }
                if (isset($options['PRECISION']) && is_numeric($options['PRECISION'])) {
                    $precision = $options['PRECISION'];
                }
            }
            $cType .= sprintf('(%d,%d)', $precision, $scale);
            break;
```